Does increasing temperature increase the rate of gaseous reactions?
In chemical kinetics there is a generalised statement that the rate of reaction is dependent upon


the concentration of reactants (except for zero order/complex reactions)
temperature
catalyst
surface area (for a solid reactant)
and, in some cases, light energy


My question is: if I increase the temperature, will the rate of reaction still increase for a reaction involving reactants and products in gaseous states?
I know that the rate constant of the reaction depends on temperature by the Arrhenius Equation, but in chemistry class we were taught that $PV = nRT$,  therefore $P = \frac{nRT}{V} \implies P = CRT$ where C is the molar concentration of the gas. Now applying derivative on both sides with respect to time,
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{dC}{dt}\times RT$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = \frac{1}{RT} \times \frac{dP}{dt}$$
and we know that the rate of a reaction = $\frac{dC}{dt}$. Therefore we obtain the rate of reaction to be varying inversely with temperature (if other parameters are kept constant) i.e. rate for a gaseous reaction $\propto \frac{1}{T}$.
So, finally, I want to know if the statement "rate of a reaction increases with increase in temperature" is a generalised statement (because we were told in our class that it is always valid), or, is it true even in case of gaseous reactions (if my explanation is wrong)?

Could you guys also please post the reasons why this question has been downvoted? This will help me in improving the standard of questions I ask in future :)

Some people like to downvote anonymously and seldom returns to read your comment. // Raise of temperature increases reaction rate of ALL reactions.
Some more than others, what leads to shifting of equilibrium with temperature. This may mean the NET reaction rate (the difference between forward and backward reaction rate) can in some cases decrease with temperature, if products are thermodynamically less favorable at higher temperature.

But then why is the rate showing inverse relation with temperature , in the expression I have given?

You have not addressed dc/dt = f(T).

Unless $\Delta n=0$, a reaction in gaseous state experiences a change in volume, which means: $-\frac{dC_A}{dt}\neq -r_A=\mathrm{rate}$, and $C=f(V)\neq \mathrm{constant}$. Higher $T$ results in higher $k$ according to Arrhenius, which translates directly to a higher reaction rate. In other words, $\mathrm{rate}=-\frac{dC_A}{dt}$ is only valid when volume remains constant, which is common in liquid phase reactions but not gaseous ones.

The rate of reaction of each step will increase because the rate constant increases as there is more energy and so more molecules can overcome the activation energy. In a complicated reaction (such as a chain reaction) you need to consider the overall equation $d[c]/dt=\cdots$ including any changes in pressure/volume.

First of all, do you know why increasing the temperature increase the reaction rate? The answer is because of energy.  The average energy of particles always increase as the temperature increase. This increase in energy helped them to overcome the energy barrier (activation energy), hence the increase of temperature always increase the reaction rate.

How is it you seem to get kinetics well, but not Clapeyron equation? In general, temperature will make reaction faster. How pressure and density are gonna influence it, is secondary issue. You assumed free expansion, which hardly has to be the case.

The reason why increasing temperature increases rate of reaction are,
i) On increasing temp you are increasing the kinetic energy of the reactants which will inevitably cause more collisions and will increase rate of reaction (r.o.r).
ii) If it were that simple to write the eqn you have written then Arrhenius Eqn would not have been a thing, the reason why what you are writing is incorrect is that you are forgetting that every term in that equation of your is intrinsically linked with temperature, pressure is linked with temperature and even concentration is. Writing this will leave you with nothing that is of use to you, since you cannot determine what will happen on increasing temp.
That when the Arrhenius Eqn comes into play and then with the help of rate law you can link temp to ror easily.
